# Get the Monday after 6 weeks in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe like this,

```
ID   Start Date
1    4/15/19
2    4/15/19
3    4/15/19
4    4/22/19
5    4/22/19
6    5/8/19
7    5/15/19
```

How can I generate a new column to get the Monday after 6 weeks?

I know how to shift the date by using `df['Next Month'] = df['Start Date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=30)` Then you can have a column with a date after one month.

My final output will be like,

```
ID   Start Date   After 6 weeks
1    4/15/19      5/27/19
2    4/15/19      5/27/19
3    4/15/19      5/27/19
4    4/22/19      6/3/19
5    4/22/19      6/3/19
6    5/8/19       6/17/19
7    5/15/19      6/24/19
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['Start Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])

df['Start'] - pd.to_timedelta(arg=df['Start'].dt.weekday, unit='D')+pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(days=6*7)
Out[117]: 
0   2019-05-27
1   2019-05-27
2   2019-05-27
3   2019-06-03
4   2019-06-03
5   2019-06-17
6   2019-06-24
Name: Start, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just a small typo up here. Use '=' when you assign a new column:)